# filtration and pagination using ajax call in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I want to do filtration and pagination in one script. I have done filtration and pagination separately. But when I combine this two code snippet pagination is not working. Here I give my code which I have done.

```
 function getusedcarFilterOptions(){
    var opts = [];
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
      if(this.checked){
        opts.push(this.name);
      }
    });

    return opts;
 }

  function updateusedcar(opts){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "filter.php",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: {filterOpts: opts},
      success: function(data){

          $('#usedcar1').html(makeTable(data));
          displayRecords();
      }
    });
  }

  var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
  $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    var opts = getusedcarFilterOptions();
    updateusedcar(opts);
  });

  updateusedcar();




      // fetching records
                        function displayRecords(numRecords, pageNum) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "getrecords.php",
                                data: "show=" + numRecords + "&pagenum=" + pageNum,
                                cache: false,
                                beforeSend: function() {
                                    $('.loader').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24" style="padding-left: 400px; margin-top:10px;" >');
                                },
                                success: function(html) {
                                    $("#usedcar1").html(makeTable(data));
                                    $('.loader').html('');
                                }
                            });
                        }

    // used when user change row limit
                        function changeDisplayRowCount(numRecords) {
                            displayRecords(numRecords, 1);
                        }

                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            displayRecords(10, 1);
                        });
    </script>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine the codes on server side, otherwise the filtered record are not paginated and vice-versa. Otherwise you need to do the pagination on client side but I suppose it would eliminate the main reason of the pagination.